# How to lnstall vinkla/hashids to Laravel 9 project

Tags: laravel, composer-php, hashids

I ran `composer require vinkla/hashids` but got the following error.

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
> packages.
> - symfony/console v6.2.3 requires php >=8.1 -> your php version (8.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
> - spatie/laravel-ignition 1.6.4 requires symfony/console ^5.0|^6.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v6.2.3].
> - spatie/laravel-ignition is locked to version 1.6.4 and an update of this package was not requested. You can also try re-running
> composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer
> require hashids/hashids:*" to figure out if any version is
> installable, or "composer require hashids/hashids:^2.1" if you know
> which you need.
>
> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to
> their original content.

My laravel project composer.json has the following code snippet.

```
"require": {
        "php": "^8.0.2",
        "aloha/twilio": "^5.0",
        "cartalyst/stripe-laravel": "^14.0",
        "classiebit/addchat-laravel": "^1.0",
        "clever/clever": "*",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^3.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "laravel-validation-rules/credit-card": "^1.7",
        "laravel/cashier": "^14.7",
        "laravel/framework": "^9.19",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^3.0",
        "laravel/socialite": "^5.5",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.8",
        "laravel/ui": "^4.2",
        "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^3.12",
        "league/oauth2-client": "^2.6",
        "microsoft/microsoft-graph": "^1.85",
        "orangehill/iseed": "^3.0",
        "pusher/pusher-php-server": "^7.2",
        "s-ichikawa/laravel-sendgrid-driver": "^4.0",
        "twilio/sdk": "^6.44",
        "whtht/intro-step": "^1.6"
    },
```

I tried different versions of hashids but the same thing is true. Is there any way to resolve it?

I tried different versions of hashids but it did not help.

Comment: *"symfony/console v6.2.3 requires php >=8.1 -> your php version (8.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement."* - Your error is pretty clear; you are running PHP `8.0.25`, but the packages you're requesting require PHP `8.1` (or above). You need to either upgrade your PHP version (should be easy), or browse through the various packages to see if there is a version that supports your version of PHP (definitely a lot harder)

Comment: No problem, and best of luck! I've always found version mismatches a pain to deal with, but it depends on how well documented the packages are re: version support. Hopefully this one cooperates 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to upgrade your PHP version to 8.1. your current PHP version is 8.0

Comment: Thanks, Rather than php upgrade, I would like to find another way. impossible?

Comment: "Impossible" - no. But why did you accept this answer if this is not the way you prefer? Why not install any older version of that package instead?

Answer (score -1):

You may use same command with additional options like

```
composer require vinkla/hashids --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Comment: That's not a good idea. I would assume that the package has a good reason to require PHP 8.1, and running it on PHP 8.0 won't work